# How to create table from another table with passing NULL values to a column?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, ddl

I'm trying to create a table with `CREATE AS SELECT` in which I want to pass `NULL` value to `col3`.

Structure of `main`:

```
SQL> desc main
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
col1                                       NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
col2                                                VARCHAR2(15)
col3                                                BLOB
col4                                                VARCHAR2(15)
```

I've tried below 2 methods:

Method 1:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(   
col1, col2, col3, col4
) AS
SELECT 
col1, col2, NULL, col4
FROM main;
```

Method 2:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(   
col1, col2, col3, col4
) AS
SELECT 
col1, col2, 'NULL', col4
FROM main;
```

In Method 2, my `col3` data type is changed from `BLOB` to `CHAR(4)`.

**I want to use one command to create** `temp`  **table and keep the data type same with table holding** `NULL` **values for `col3`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BLOBs you should use the  [`EMPTY_BLOB`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions047.htm) instead of `NULL`:

```
SQL> desc main;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                      NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 COL2                                               VARCHAR2(15)
 COL3                                               BLOB
 COL4                                               VARCHAR2(15)

SQL> create table temp ( col1, col2, col3, col4)
  2  as select col1, col2, empty_blob(), col4
  3  from main;

Table created.

SQL> desc temp;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                      NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 COL2                                               VARCHAR2(15)
 COL3                                               BLOB
 COL4                                               VARCHAR2(15)
```